# How to mask clouds in ER Mapper?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, digital-image-processing, er-mapper

I am using ER Mapper. But, I'm still confused how to detect and mask the clouds.

I want to reduce or eliminate the cloud to perform supervised and unsupervised classification.

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS StackExchange! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Question is what kind of imagery you are using? You can detect and mask clouds "easily" in Landsat, the more bands you have the easier it can be especially you have thermal band. I am doing classifications as well but in another system. But we have the problems as well with clouds, actually more with the shadows of the clouds. You cant classify a shadowed pixel, the result wouldnt be correct.